# Why the function $x\mapsto \nu(E_x)$ is measurable for $E_x$ is the section set of $E$ in a product space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal X, \eta)$ and $(Y,\mathcal Y, \nu)$ be measure spaces and denote $(X\times Y, \mathcal X \otimes \mathcal Y, \eta \times \nu)$ be the usual product measure space. I assume that they are **NOT** $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.

Let $E \in \mathcal X \otimes \mathcal Y$. I would like to prove that the map $x\mapsto \nu(E_x)$ is measurable (from $X$ to $[0,\infty]$), where $E_x:= \{y \in Y: (x,y) \in E \}$ is a section set which I know is measurable. In the $\sigma$-finite measure case, I know how to do it using Monotone Class Theorem.

**Question:** Is is still true that $x\mapsto \nu(E_x)$ is still measurable in general measure spaces? If not, could we provide a counter-example?

Any hints are highly appreciated since I don't know where to start.

Comment: This is a particular case of Fubini's theorem for the characteristic function of $E$, so I'd look that theorem up in a textbook to get an idea how it's proved.

Comment: I apologize for not being so precise. I know this is true for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces (I edited above). However, my question concerns more general spaces, for which I couldn't find in textbooks.

Comment: I think I recall Follands book having or at least citing an example where the measurability fails as a counterexample to Tonellis theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked: Is it still true that $x\mapsto \nu(E_x)$ is still measurable in general measure spaces?

Answer: No. Here is a counterexample.

Consider $([0,1],\Sigma, \lambda)$  where $\Sigma$ is Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.  Let $V \subseteq [0,1]$ be a set that is NOT Lebesgue measurable. Consider also $([0,1],\Sigma, \nu)$  where $\nu$ is the measure defined by $\nu(\{a\}) = 1$ if $a\notin V$ and $\nu(\{a\}) = 2$ if $a\in V$. Clearly, $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Let $E = \{(x,x) : x \in [0,1]\}$, the diagonal of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Clearly $E \in \Sigma \otimes \Sigma$ and, we have that, each section $E_x:= \{y \in Y: (x,y) \in E \}$ is measurable.

However, the map $x\mapsto \nu(E_x)$ (from $[0,1]$ to $[0,\infty]$) is NOT measurable. This maps coincides with $\chi_V +1$ and we know $\chi_V$ is not (Lebesgue) measurable ($\chi_V$  is the indicator function of $V$).